# android appwidget getting unresponsive after some time

Tags: android, appwidgetprovider

I have developed an app widget which has simple buttons  displaying "+" and "-" and a text field displaying the counter on incrementing/decrementing. Everything works like a charm after we drag the widget to the home screen. After some time, the system sleeps and after it wakes up, I try to click buttons but they become unresponsive and the text field does not changes. I don't get any calls on "onReceive" method of class extending the AppWidgetProvider.

I read that If this BroadcastReceiver was launched through a  tag, then the object is no longer alive after returning from this function at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent).

Is that the problem? If yes, then how can we use the service to handle broadcasts for the appwidget?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: are you developing on marshmallow?

Comment: No, I am doing on Kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to this query. Sorry for posting it late. Basically I have started a service from onUpdate of the widgetprovider and in onreceive for different buttons, starting service with different intents that we want to distinguish the buttons clicks on.

You need to start service with START_STICKY.